# How would I chown everything found by grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am looking to chown all files that contain the word "hi"

I currently have

```
grep -r $1 $2
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Found text"
        echo $match
        echo "start"
```

with input being something such as `./test.sh "hi" *`

I am able to obtain all files that contain hi however when I attempt to chown I am not sure what to put with piping I know that you can pass the variables to the next argument such as;

```
grep -r $1 $2 | chown user1:root *
```

but that seems to just do the entire directory and that's not what I wanted.

Any suggestions on what to read or look into to pass this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the `xargs` command.  It reads a sequence of strings from its standard input and converts them to arguments to the command specified.  For example:

```
grep -r --files-with-matches $1 $2 | xargs chown user1:root
```

**Update:**

Commenters suggested techniques for hardening the above command, which is indeed a good idea.  Since `$1` and `$2` are command-line arguments to your script, you cannot be confident, in general, that they do not contain whitespace or other characters that would change the meaning of the command.  It is a good idea, therefore, to quote them.  Additionally, if any of the file names include whitespace -- including in any directory names in the included path segments -- then `xargs` will misinterpret the results unless you help it out.  Here's a version of the pipeline that is more robust against such things:

```
grep -rlZ "$1" "$2" | xargs -0 chown user1:root
```

This version depends on GNU extensions to both `grep` and `xargs`.  The `-Z` option causes `grep` to separate output "lines" with a zero-valued character instead of with a newline, and the `-0` argument to `xargs` tells it to interpret the incoming data accordingly.  That character has the unique distinction of not being permitted in Unix file names.

The `-l` option (a lowercase L, not a numeral 1) to `grep` is the short form of GNU's `--with-file-names` option; the short form will be supported by any POSIX-compliant `grep`.  I present it here for both completeness and brevity.

Comment: Might pay to change the **xargs** part to **xargs -i chown user1:root "{}"** in case there are odd characters in the names ;}

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works. Could you expain why when using xargs you don't have to specify the directory path after user1:root ?

Comment: @21days, `xargs` just takes the file names exactly as `grep` outputs them, and converts them into arguments.  If your `grep` locates a file in a subdirectory, then the file name it reports will contain the necessary leading elements of a path to that file.  `xargs` doesn't do anything magical; it just uses what is given to it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah I see, that makes sense! Well, it's certainly helped me out and solved the issue.

Comment: Since you're using GNU `grep`, you might as well render the command robust with the `-Z` flag to `grep` and the `-0` flag to `xargs`. Oh, and you should quote the expansions `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, agreed, and I have updated my answer.  I acknowledge, too, that a fully POSIX-compliant alternative could be written according to tink's suggestion, but the semantics would not be the same -- `xargs` would run a separate `chown` command for each input line, instead of grouping arguments and performing fewer `chown`s overall.